# Virtual Terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm new on Ubuntu so I've some problem when I switch between GUI and Virtual Terminal, infact when I enter in Virtual Terminal I cannot see the upper right part because the screen looks like liquid crystal have been damaged.
I'am attaching a photo.

[image]

Thank you everybody

Comment: Can you use the terminal app in the GUI?

Comment: That could be a graphics error, do you have a graphics card, if so, have you installed the drivers?

Comment: Yes I've a Nvidia graphics card, I think I've installed all the drivers but I'm not sure of it. But for power saving I've selected the Intel Graphics card